# Download a file from a bucket with a different region than s3 client is

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to download a file from a bucket with a region that differs from s3 client bucket?
Example:
s3Client with region us-east wants do download a file from a bucket in us-west.

I found WithS3UseARNRegion - but documentation does not say much about in what cases I should use it or how.

Comment: You can't.  You need to instruct the S3 Client which region the bucket is in, or allow it to detect the bucket's region by using us-east-1, if your SDK supports that functionality.

Comment: @AnonCoward what did you mean by saying `detect the bucket's region by using us-east-1`?

Comment: Some of the AWS SDKs will respond to the incorrect region error message when requesting information from S3 that us-east-1 responses generate by re-targeting the request to the correct region.  No idea if your SDK/Language behaves like this since you've not stated which one you're using.

Comment: @AnonCoward aws-sdk-go